# WordPress: How do i test if one or more sidebars have widgets?

Tags: php, wordpress

Quick overview of what i am trying to do. I have a template layout that has 3 columns the left and right column are widget areas. What i would like to do is test for if both widget areas are active, one of widget areas are active, or if none are active (ie. have widget content).

Examples code:

```
    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar_1' && 'sidebar_2') ) { ?>
        <div class="bothSidebarsActive"></div>
    <?php } elseif ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar_1' || 'sidebar_2' ) { ?>
        <div class="OneTheSidebarsActive"></div>
   <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="noneOfTheSidebarsAreActive"></div>                              
   <?php }; ?>
```

I have had limited success getting the IF or ELSEIF to return true, but never all three states. Anybody know what i am doing wrong ?

Thank you for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to - BULK for the assistance the code now works, here it is in case anybody else comes across this same issue.

functional code:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar ( 'employees_sidebar' ) && is_active_sidebar ( 'contact_sidebar' ) ) { ?>
      <div class="bothSidebarsActive"></div>
<?php } elseif ( is_active_sidebar ( 'employees_sidebar' ) || is_active_sidebar ( 'contact_sidebar' ) ) { ?>
      <div class="OneSidebarActive"></div>
<?php } else { ?>
      <div class="noneOfTheSidebarsAreActive"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`elseif ( 'employees_sidebar' || 'contact_sidebar' )` looks like your issue to me. You should be using the `is_active_sidebar` function here also. Like this:

```
<?php } elseif ( is_active_sidebar('employees_sidebar') || is_active_sidebar('contact_sidebar') ) { ?>
```

Comment: arg, i am sorry that is a type *facepalm. Will edit this to make more sense. Sorry

Comment: If your edit is accurate the line is still wrong (and now a syntax error..)

Comment: I keep finding additional mistakes in the exampled code, simple types. I have been starring at this code for way to long :P To the best of my knowledge this edit should be accurate.

Comment: Your current code still won't execute from syntax errors. You're not closing the bracked for the `elseif` statement. Additionally you're still using `is_active_sidebar` wrong... My answer still stands, see how it's formed and change the sidebar names if you need. Edit: the miss-using of `is_active_sidebar` also applies to the first line.

Comment: Thank you i see it now, does the same apply for the <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar_1' && 'sidebar_2') ) { ?> ??

Comment: Yes indeed it does :)

Comment: Thank you so much kind sir, i swear sometimes you can stare yourself blind at your own code. It makes perfect sense now.